# How to get value of dynamically added fields while doing Form Editing in JqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have one jqgrid which is having few columns. One of the column represent URLs. While showing the data in grid format, every url apears one after another seperated by ;(semicolon). When I double click a row, I get Form Window and in block `onInitializeForm` based on number of ;(semicolon)'s count, I am showing every URL in different inputbox. So the user can edit/update each one individualy.

But I am getting problem when there are more than one URL entry and after making changes when I submit the window, I get only first URL's data in my beans attribute. Others just get disappeared.

I saw the `postdata` in 'beforeSubmit' method and this is also showing only first input box's value.

Could you please help me, how to get value from those dynamically added extra fields?

If you need more info, please tell me. I am stuck on this for more than three days.

**Update** :-

What I did is,

in

```
beforeSubmit : function(postdata, formid) { 
       var val=";";
       $("p textarea").each(function (index) {  
        val = val + $("#p_scnt" +(index+1)).val() + ";"; 
    });
    $('#url').val($("#url").val() + val);  
    return[true, ""];
 }
```

"url" is my jqgrid column and "p_scnt" is the id of all newly created textboxes.

Its not setting valud back to URL column

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using another way.

```
beforeSubmit : function(postdata, formid) { 
    var val=";";
    $("p textarea").each(function (index) {  
      val = val + $("#p_scnt" +(index+1)).val() + ";"; 
    });

    postdata["url"] = postdata["url"] +  val;
    return[true, ""];
}
```